# How to create a conditional and chainable query method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have three models: `Post`, `Comment` and `User`.

When commenting on a post, the user can choose to "Show only for post author" and the `Comment` attribute `public` gets a `false` value.

The method should only return private comments if they belong to `current_user` or if it's post author who's querying.

How would I construct the conditional `exclude_unauthorized_privates` method and in which model should it go?

```
post.ordered_comments.exclude_unauthorized_privates
```

Comment: Are you using the gem, `acts_as_commentable` for your comments?

Comment: No I'm not, I'm interested about this general idea to create a query with conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this.

On your `Post` model I would create a method like this:

```
def is_author?
  current_user.id == user_id
end
```

This will allow you to check if the `current_user` on the page is the author of the post.

Then on your `Comment` model I would add this scope:

```
scope :public, lambda { |user_id|
  where("user_id = ? OR public = ?", user_id, 1)
}
```

Then to get the comments to display on the page from your controller I would set your `@comments` to this:

```
@comments = post.is_author? post.ordered_comments : post.ordered_comments.public(current_user.id)
```

This will pass the `@comments` variable to your view and you will have only the comments showing that should be showing to the `current_user`.

Comment: This allows current_user to view all private comments (not only her own).

Comment: The user_id on is_author? is the id listed in the db for the belongs_to relationship. That would allow the post author to see all comments and all others to not see the private comments.

Comment: Yes, each commet has an `user_id`. To clarify: the post author should see all comments. An ordinary user should not see any private comments except for her own.

Comment: Ahh okay. I updated the answer to reflect that the ordinary user should still be able to see their own private comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying post should have just one method on it, it's a demeter violation otherwise. Just have post delegate :ordered_authorized_comments to comments.

I think you should probably use [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) for this one. I think the query needs to be something like "where private: true or user: [poster, commentor]" (except with the correct syntax). Getting the OR in there is easier done with arel than a ugly sql statement. You're choice of course.